# Sporadic problem with System.IO.Streamwriter in VB.net where it creates the file but comes up with an error that I can't write lines to the file

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I've been having some problems with StreamWriter writing to a file sporadically lately and hopefully someone can try to shed some light on it. My call to the subroutine is the following:

```
<!--Code Start
SubPrint(tagVal)
--> End of Code
```

And the sub is simply this at the moment where I am just populating the array with some random numbers. (I'll later be iterating through real data and populating it that way):

```
<!--Code Start
Public Sub SubPrint(item As String)
    Dim sw As StreamWriter =
        New StreamWriter("C:\Users\dlawrence\Desktop\Fred.txt", False)
    Dim tags() As Integer = {1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2}
    Dim max As Integer = tags(0)
    For i = 1 To tags.Count - 1
        If tags(i) > max Then
            max = tags(i)
        End If
             sw.WriteLine(tags(i).ToString) 'EDIT moved this out of the If
    Next


End Sub
--> End of Code
```

It creates the file "Fred.txt" on my desktop at runtime, but throws the exception error:

```
<!--Error Log Start
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80070020
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\dlawrence\Desktop\Fred.txt' because it is being used by another process.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at Tagging_App_GUI.Form1.SubPrint(String item) in C:\Users\dlawrence\Documents\iLogicIdeasForPunchedWindows\TagAddIn\New AddIn\NewGUI\Tagging App GUI\Tagging App GUI\Form1.vb:line 184
   at Tagging_App_GUI.Form1.BtnTag_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\dlawrence\Documents\iLogicIdeasForPunchedWindows\TagAddIn\New AddIn\NewGUI\Tagging App GUI\Tagging App GUI\Form1.vb:line 150
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun() in f:\dd\vb\runtime\msvbalib\ApplicationServices\WindowsFormsApplicationBase.vb:line 779
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel() in f:\dd\vb\runtime\msvbalib\ApplicationServices\WindowsFormsApplicationBase.vb:line 1471
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine) in f:\dd\vb\runtime\msvbalib\ApplicationServices\WindowsFormsApplicationBase.vb:line 452
   at Tagging_App_GUI.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
--> End of Error logging
```

I've had luck writing to it the other day in a different section of code, but not today. I am using the Imports statement to get both the system and IO name spaces via Imports System.IO  A restart of the system produced no joy. There was an inside Exception whose value was Nothing...

Can anyone see something I'm not seeing? Thank you!

Comment: Is it always a new file every time the method is called, or are there times where you call it when the file already exists and you intend to overwrite or append to it?

Comment: Oh, I've tried the append arguments as well. In fact I simplified that one b/c I had that set to False so the constructor will create (or overwrite) every time.  In fact, I just tried a simple console app and a quick and dirty new bit and still no joy:

Comment: You still didn't answer my question.  Which are you doing?  Always creating a new file, or appending to one that's already there?

Comment: Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Dim TagVal As String = "HH1"
    Sub Main()

        SubPrint(TagVal)

    End Sub
    Public Sub SubPrint(item As String)
        Dim sw As StreamWriter =
        New StreamWriter("C:\Users\dlawrence\Desktop\Fred.txt", False)
        Dim tags() As Integer = {1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2}
        Dim max As Integer = tags(0)
        For i = 1 To tags.Count - 1
            If tags(i) > max Then
                max = tags(i)
            End If
            sw.Write(tags(i).ToString) 'EDIT moved this out of the If
        Next


    End Sub
End Module

Comment: I'm going to be creating one that's not there.

Comment: So the method is never called again to append to it or overwrite it after it was created by a previous call to the method?

Comment: It will be called repeatedly in other places and be overwritten. Its purpose is to be a temporary place holder file that I then use streamreader to read from and move on in the program. It will be called any number of times.

Comment: Then the problem is that you never dispose the `StreamWriter`, therefore it won't necessarily close the file right away.  Consider declaring the variable inside a `Using` block.

Comment: Using the *Using* statement or explicitly using StreamWriter.Close() is never optional.  You gotta close that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not `closing` the `StreamWriter` thus every time you try to write to it again it's in use, hence the `Error`.

Add `sw.Close` after the `Next` line like so:

```
    Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\dlawrence\Desktop\Fred.txt")
    Dim tags() As Integer = {1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2}
    Dim max As Integer = tags(0)
    For i = 1 To tags.Count - 1
        If tags(i) > max Then
            max = tags(i)
        End If
        sw.WriteLine(tags(i).ToString) 'EDIT moved this out of the If
    Next
    sw.Close()
```

or better still, use a `Using` block when using `StreamWriter` like so:

```
    Using sw As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\dlawrence\Desktop\Fred.txt")
        Dim tags() As Integer = {1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2}
        Dim max As Integer = tags(0)
        For i = 1 To tags.Count - 1
            If tags(i) > max Then
                max = tags(i)
            End If
            sw.WriteLine(tags(i).ToString) 'EDIT moved this out of the If
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Oh damn. I had that close() commented out in my original code, too. Thanks a ton! ... now I may also set it to nothing too after I see the memory stack. 